# A film with action. Maybe romance. Definitely coffee.

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

So I have this movie script I want to start pitching to major studios. The only problem is that I can't come up with a name for the film. Can you help me out? Below is a description of the opening scene.

> An Indonesian crime lord is sitting in his living room, sipping coffee. Two of his henchmen are in the next room rehearsing a script. The others are playing a board game.
>
> A loud noise approaches from a distance. A man driving a motorcycle pulls into the driveway, parks his vehicle, and puts out his cigarette. He walks up to the door and knocks.
>
> "Who is it?" asks the crime lord in the local language.
>
> The man cracks his knuckles, answers "The garbage collector", and kicks down the door.

So, any ideas how to name this film?

Comment: Is it worth protecting this puzzle? I feel people are just giving movie titles at this point without explanations, even though the correct answer is several hours old.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the title should definitely include the word

> Java

Because this word is related to many aspects of the opening scene:

> The Indonesian crime lord might be from [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java), Indonesia
>  He sips coffee, for which an AmE slang term is "java"
>  Two of his henchmen are rehearsing a script. Perhaps not a movie script but [Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)?
>  The others are playing a board game. Perhaps [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(board_game))?
>  Surely too the motorcyclist is smoking Russian [Java Cigarettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(cigarette)).
>  Finally, the [Garbage Collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) arrives to remove outdated references in languages such as [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)).

Also, it's a bit of a stretch but perhaps the Motorcycle is from:

> The company [Jawa Moto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jawa_Moto)

Comment: Since the title includes "definitely coffee" it might be in the direction of coffeescript. (a preprocessor language for javascript)

Comment: There is also a language called rot13(Wninarfr) for the third paragraph

Comment: @Umbozz "definitely" there will be  a large amount of "coffee" in a movie about wnin-cebtenzzref (rot13)

Answer (score 0):

> Strong Java 
>  Coffee Grinder 
>  Grounds for Vengeance 
>  Black and Bitter 
>  Cold Brew 
>  Murderccino

Comment: Make sure to add a ">!" before each line to avoid giving spoilers!

Comment: LOL, Murderccino sounds great. "Double espresso, some milk foam, blood of my enemies..."

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This is a good answer, but could definitely use some explanation (see EightAndAHalfTails' answer, above) as to why your answer is correct. Usually (from what I've seen), the answer is important but the explanation is at least as important as the answer itself!

Comment: (@jafe, I personally enjoyed both Murderccino and Grounds for Vengeance, that last one sounds like the subtitle of the next Die Hard movie)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could work:

> The Deadly Blend

Comment: While this appears to be a perfectly suitable name for the film, it does need more explanation as to why it is the best answer in the context of the puzzle.

Answer (score -2):

Definitely you should go for

> "Java - the Hunt"

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This is a good answer, but could definitely use some explanation (see EightAndAHalfTails' answer, above) as to why your answer is correct. Usually (from what I've seen), the answer is important but the explanation is at least as important as the answer itself!

Comment: @El-Guest Does "Java - the Hunt" represent something real? Looks like it is a good pun but a bad answer...

Comment: @xhienne I thought it was a pun on Jabba the Hutt. At any rate, I stand by my comment at the top of this page; I think the post should be protected to stop random additional answers (such as this one and all of the non-accepted answers) from filtering in long after the correct answer has been given.